# how to make pagination to display every page in PDF file using java swing?

Tags: java, swing, pagination, pdfbox, pdf-viewer

I am developing pdf viewer in java swing using the Apache pdfbox library. I can able to display only one page in the pdf file, but I want to display every page in the pdf file. So I need to create pagination like in JavaFX same in the swing to display every page in the pdf file.

Here my code :

```
 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import java.awt.Image;
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.net.URL;
 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;

 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;

public class Viewer {

   public static void main(String avg[]) throws Exception {

   FileInputStream file = new 
   FileInputStream("/home/enad2/Documents/Vicky/file/Karnataka_holiday_list2020.PDF");
   PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
   PDFRenderer render = new PDFRenderer(document);
   BufferedImage myPicture = render.renderImage(0);
   JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));  
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   frame.setSize(1404, 1872);

   frame.add(picLabel);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
 }
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this... one method is used in PDFDebugger, have a look at its source code.

Comment: So .. call `BufferedImage myPicture = render.renderImage(0);` in a loop from 0 to the number of pages and display those. Memory limits might mean it is better to have a single label with forward / back buttons to increment the pages and display one at a time. Try something using either of those two approaches, or any other you can think up, but get back to us when / if you strike a specific problem. Voting to close.

Comment: using loop getting an error, because variable using outside of the loop. so if we provide loop for BufferedImage myPicture = render.renderImage(0); myPicture became a local variable, then we can't use myPicture outside of the loop.

Comment: Can anyone have sample code or any link?

Comment: https://downloads.apache.org/pdfbox/2.0.19/pdfbox-2.0.19-src.zip there the PDFDebugger subproject but this is huge. IMHO creating a viewer from scratch is bigger than the usual SO question. You should first create an application that does only the pagination and prints out a number. Then in a next step the PDFBox stuff.

Comment: *"using loop getting an error"* Tip: Add @TilmanHausherr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. BTW - *what* error? Always copy/paste error and exception output as an [edit] to the question!